# Create closure returning iterator on string

Tags: rust, iterator, closures, lifetime

I want to write a closure that takes an object and returns an iterator from it. The idea is to store the closure in a structure and apply as needed:

```
fn main() {
    let iter_wrap = |x: &String| Box::new(x.chars());
    let test = String::from("test");

    for x in iter_wrap(&test) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

This causes the error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter in function call due to conflicting requirements
 --> src/main.rs:2:45
  |
2 |     let iter_wrap = |x: &String| Box::new(x.chars());
  |                                             ^^^^^
  |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 2:21...
 --> src/main.rs:2:21
  |
2 |     let iter_wrap = |x: &String| Box::new(x.chars());
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:2:43
  |
2 |     let iter_wrap = |x: &String| Box::new(x.chars());
  |                                           ^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the call at 5:14...
 --> src/main.rs:5:14
  |
5 |     for x in iter_wrap(&test) {
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that argument is valid for the call
 --> src/main.rs:5:14
  |
5 |     for x in iter_wrap(&test) {
  |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I tried to change `String` to `Vec` and remove boxing, but the result is the same.

How can I make it compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closures with borrows in parameter or return types have some known bugs as shown in this issue report and the others it links to: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58052

There are a few ways to work around the issue.

[Using fully qualified syntax](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f2bb18dc5fecb5f54299705525556bae)

```rust
fn main() {
    let iter_wrap = |x| Box::new(str::chars(x));
    let test = String::from("test");

    for x in iter_wrap(&test) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

[Using a type annotation in the closure body](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=62a5360e95c753bfd2a9899a257c494a)

```rust
fn main() {
    let iter_wrap = |x| {let x: &String = x; Box::new(x.chars()) };
    let test = String::from("test");

    for x in iter_wrap(&test) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you try to achieve there, but basically just looking at your provided example, you don't need a closure, but a function:

```rust
use std::str::Chars;

fn main() {
    fn iter_wrap(s: &str) -> Chars {
        s.chars()
    }

    let test = "test".to_string();

    for c in iter_wrap(&test) {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Or you could have a closure, that is *enclosing* the outside world, in this case, your string:

```rust
fn main() {
    let test = "test".to_string();
    let iter_wrap = || test.chars();

    for c in iter_wrap() {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: "It should accept parameter and return an iterator" -- in which case, why does it have to be a closure?

Comment: Good question, probably this is my strong C++ background where we have lambda expressions that may be stored as functions or passed to other functions.

Comment: @Alex we have that in Rust as well :) That's not the question.  If you are not enclosing anything from the surrounding world, it doesn't make sense to opt-in for a bigger thing (closures are "fat" functions), when you can have the nice and slim function pointer.

Comment: Ok, do we have anonymous functions? It would be great to skip giving a name for a single time used function.

Comment: Note that closures that don't capture anything, as it is the case here, are not any fatter than a function pointer and actually coerce to `fn`.

Comment: If it is a function pointer that would mean your function is not changing depending on your context (which would otherwise be the case with a closure).  Therefore, it doesn't make any sense to create them on the fly, you would create and name the ones that you need, and store one of them in your `struct` based on some criteria.

Comment: @stephaneyfx in practice, that is indeed true, however you still can't pass a closure to a function accepting function pointer only and not `Fn` traits.

Comment: @PeterVaro A closure implicitly coerces to a `fn` pointer if it does not capture anything. This compiles: `fn foo(_: fn(i32) -> i32) {} fn main() { foo(|x| x + 2); }` [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3d295c46b7737055f2648b6950e2a061)

Comment: @PeterVaro That makes sense in a case where the `struct` is generic and closure is essentially adapter. As a reference, you may just look at the `<algorithm>` library in `C++`. All the algorithms become useful the mostly with lambda expressions, because they provide flexibility.

Comment: @stephaneyfx nice one, I did not know about that!

Comment: @Alex if you have further requirements, then I suggest to edit your question and the provided example to mention those needs.

Comment: Well, I just though I provided minimal working example, but it looks like every new layer requires different solution. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Alex that's exactly the case! It is very hard to come up with a minimal working solution that has all the constraints your actual implementation has.  (And IMO that's especially true when it comes to Rust.)

Comment: Just because the change will be too huge, I'll do it as another one question.

Comment: @Alex I see no reason to completely rewrite this question if the current one does not reflect your actual problem.  But it is your call.  If you decide you will open a new one, I would at least put a comment about this into this thread as a future reference for people if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define and use a lifetime that is shorter than the lifetime of the function itself. I tried this and it worked:

```
fn foo<'a, 'b: 'a>() {
    let test = String::from("test");
    let iw = |x: &'b String| {
        x.chars()
    };

    for x in iw(&test) {
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    foo()
}
```

Just using lifetime `'a` is not sufficient, you need a lifetime that is *shorter* than that, so `'b: 'a`.

Now what I cannot explain is that, with both 'a and 'b defined, using `&'a String` in the closure definition works as well ...