# "Cannot infer an appropriate lifetime" when calling lambda

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let get = |v: &u32| -> &u32 {
        v
    };
    let x : u32 = 0;
    let y = get(&x);
}
```

This [produces an error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72db1207e2df87ec1d98a3c5196cdd44): `cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements` which I don't understand. If I make the lambda a free function it works fine.

How can I make this code compile?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create closure returning iterator on string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56724730/create-closure-returning-iterator-on-string)

Comment: It led me to [this link](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58052) which I don't understand either, but has a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it's a known Rust limitation which is being considered. [Discussed here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58052).